# Is the charge of an electron an upper bound?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, charge

I've been looking around and had a conversation with my professor on quantization of charge as a colleague of mine posed a question I can't seem to find a good answer for.

How do we know that the value we have for the quantum of charge, 1.6E-19 is in fact the quantum, and not just an upper bound for whatever the quantum actually is?

Maybe there's a simple explanation but I can't think of one yet. The point my colleague was making is how do we know that charge is quantized at e, if a lot of the experiments we do derive this quantity in a way where we can't necessarily determine an infimum. I mean currently we say $q=1.6\times10^{-19}$ but it would follow that if $\sup{q} = 1.6\times10^{-19}$ then you could in a sense construct formulae, say $\psi(q, t, x)$ which usually hold q as constant, to be $\psi(2q, t, x)$, and in this system the quantised charge is half that of what we currently is is so 0.8E-19. Because we can in theory divide the quantum by any number which preserves say, n, as an integer, we can keep dividing the charge (for example if $n=2^k$). In this case we would still observe (thinking of say Millikan's experiment say) that all charge is an integral multiple of some number and reach the same conclusion, because if charge in general can be expressed as $q=ez, z\in\mathbb{Z}$ then it follows that $q=(e/2)*2z$ since $2z\in \mathbb{Z}$. However in this case, the quantum of charge is a different number.

The closest idea to an answer is that given two experimentally calculated charges, if we construct/observe the experiment in such a way that $q_1 = a*e, a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q_2 = b*e, b\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there is no way we can divide the charge and maintain the integer observation, and in only this case may we falsifiably conclude the quantum to be e. I'm not sure if this is sufficient so I was wondering on people's thoughts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that quark charges are multiples of $\frac{1}{3}e$.

Comment: Yes, the oil drop experiment leaves the possibility that the charge is e/2. But if true, you need to explain why a charge of e/2 is never seen by the oil drop experiment or any other. [Charge of an Electron: Millikan's Oil Drop Experiment](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=millikan+oil+drop+experiment#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:92bd79c0,vid:2HhaQtvICe8,st:0).